# Get a random number betwen 1-200 but leaves out numbers read from query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a random number between, lets say 1-200, but at the same time I need to prevent selecting a random number that has already been used for a particular `REMOTE_ADDR` (as stored in a table).

This is what I have so far (I have tried several different approaches):

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query7 = "
SELECT * 
FROM IP
WHERE IP = '$ip'
";

$result7 = mysql_query($query7) or die(mysql_error());
$rows7 = mysql_num_rows($result7);

while ($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($result7)){
    $id = $row7['ID'];
}
```

I'm using the random number to pick an image to display, but my users are complaining  that the images selected for them is not random enough; ie, the same picture is getting "randomly" selected too often, sometimes showing the same image over and over.

It does not have to be in PHP, if there is another option.

Comment: Simpler suggestion: create a list of all images, shuffle it, store it in the user's session, pick them one by one. Random list without repeats.

Comment: I've never used sessions and I guess its kinda hard to learn

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes that you have 200 items, and collect the items which you do not want to show. Alternatively, you can query only id's of available items and choose from these, you would need to create a table with available items for that.*

Create a map which maps consecutive numbers to (non-consecutive) available numbers. Suppose the numbers 1 and 3 are in use, you can map to 2 and 4 (and so on).

Actually, it is possible to use a simple array (not-associative) for this. You can do something like this:

```
$reserved = array(1, 3); // fill $reserved using your code
$available = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 200; $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $reserved)) {
        $available[] = $i;
    }
}

if (count($available) > 0) {
    $random_index = rand(0, count($available) - 1);
    $r = $available[$random_index];
} else {
    // Nothing available!
}
```

There will be nothing to choose when you run out of pictures that have not been displayed yet. In this case, `count($available)` will be zero. One way to solve this would be to clear your list of displayed images for the current IP and choose again; see also other answers for this.

Comment: Dont I have to do this manually then? Becouse these numbers are changing all the time.

Comment: Make sure your `$reserved` is kept up-to-date.

Comment: That look pretty good, but i gett this "syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 5" and I cant see why, it looks correct to me.

Comment: Ah my bad, there should be two `))` after `$reserved`, fixed it.

Comment: Now it works great, but I till have a question, lets say that i get the numbers 31, 109, 3, 192 from the database when i look up what pictures the specific IP have seen, do I put them lite this: $reserved = array(31, 109, 3, 192);   Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that would make sure that these will not get selected.

Comment: This did not work, you can try it your self here: http://www.pixholder.com/trueshit/test.php

Comment: It also seems to only pick numbers between 100 and 150, which is odd. Could you somehow print the PHP code you are using in the page you linked to?

Comment: Your current code seems to loop infinitely (got a timeout on the page) after it runs out of numbers. FYI: Please also consider Brent Baisley's solution using SQL and an extra table.

Comment: I have an exra table already, I got one named Trueshit wich look like this: ID, URL, Views, Tags, DATE, True2, WTF, Pro and then I got tabel IP and that looks like this: Date, IP, ID I just did't know what to replace with what in his sqlstring hehe

Comment: Just puzzle and try a bit more. The demo page you provided seems a handy test. I'm sure you will find it out eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Run your select and instead of using *, only select the id column. Then use:

```
while($row7[] = mysql_fetch_array($query7));
do{
  $rand = rand(0,200);
}while(in_array($rand,$row7));
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` retrieves only one row, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php.

Comment: FYI: now `$row7` will contain something like `{{1}, {3}}`. The function `in_array` will not match `1` with `{1}`. Also, after fix, this would result in an infinite loop when all numbers occur in `$row7`. And `rand($min, $max)` is including `$max`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like that

```
// all ids from 1 to 100
$all = array_fill(1, 200, 0);

// remove used
foreach ($used as $i) {
   unset($all[$i]);
}

// get survived keys
$keys = array_keys($all);

// get random position, note that the array with keys is 0 based
$j = rand(0, count($all) - 1);

return $keys[$j];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in mysql. Have one table that has your list of images, and another table that has the list of IP addresses and the images that have already been shown to that IP. Then you select and join the tables and order the result randomly.

```
SELECT image_id FROM images 
LEFT JOIN shown_images ON images.image_id=shown_images.image_id AND ip_addr=[#.#.#.#]
WHERE shown_images.image_id IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

After you show an image to an IP, just insert a record into the shown_images table with the IP and the image ID. That will work right up until that have seen all the images. Then you can delete the records and start over.

Comment: Nice complete SQL solution, including what to do after the user has seen them all.

Comment: You'll have to excuse me but I have no ide what I should change to what, could you maybe help me? I got one table named IP and it looks like this: Date, IP, ID and oneother, Trueshit who looks like this: ID, URL, Views, Tags, DATE, True2, WTF, Pro

Comment: So Im trying to get this to work now but I get this "Column 'ID' in field list is ambiguous" from what ive read thats becouse theres a ID colomn in both tables. This is what I got so far: SELECT ID FROM Trueshit LEFT JOIN IP ON Trueshit.ID=IP.ID AND IP='$ip' WHERE IP.ID IS NULL ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

Comment: You just need to put the table name before the field name so it knows which field to pull. SELECT Trueshit.ID FROM ...